# Passing VueJS Prop into TypeScript class component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-class-components

I have a simple typescript component class that requires one prop:

```
export default class ColorsPallet extends Vue {
        @Prop({type: String, required: true}) readonly name!: string;
        private readonly view: StorageItem;
        private readonly stored: StorageItem;
        private readonly colors: ColorItems;

        constructor() {
            super();

            this.colors = db.colors[this.name]['items'];
            this.storedColor = new StorageItem(this.name + '-stored-color', localStorage, db.colors[this.name]['default']);
            this.viewColor = new StorageItem(this.name + '-view-color', sessionStorage, this.storedColor.get());
        }
}
```

I would love to initialize this class in a different typescript component class to get a specific instance variable:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    const colors = new ColorsPallet();
    console.log(color.$data.viewColor.get());
}
```

This gives me an obvious error:

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "name"

(found in <Root>)
```

So I changed the initialization to:

```
const colors = new ColorsPallet({props: ['name']})
```

That still gives me a type error as I am not really passing anything:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)
```

Without requiring a prop this code works perfectly for me in different cases. However I am not able to get this working with passing down a prop. How do I go about it?

**Edit:**

Passing prop like this also does not work:

```
const colors = new ColorsPallet({
  name: 'foo'
})
```

Results into this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ props: { name: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>'.   Types of property 'props' are incompatible.     Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string[] | RecordPropsDefinition<Record<string, any>> | undefined'.       Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

The type of required format:

```
/**
 * This type should be used when an array of strings is used for a component's `props` value.
 */
export type ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<V extends Vue, Data, Methods, Computed, PropNames extends string> =
  object &
  ComponentOptions<V, DataDef<Data, Record<PropNames, any>, V>, Methods, Computed, PropNames[], Record<PropNames, any>> &
  ThisType<CombinedVueInstance<V, Data, Methods, Computed, Readonly<Record<PropNames, any>>>>;
```

Comment: off topic but consider that TS class composition is deprecated from 2.6.x

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to set a default value:

```js
@Prop({type: String, required: true, default: 'foo'}) readonly name!: string;
```

However, in your above example I believe you would need:

```js
const colors = new ColorsPallet({
  propsData: {
    name: 'foo'
  }
})
```

Comment: ```TS2345: Argument of type '{ props: { name: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>'.   Types of property 'props' are incompatible.     Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string[] | RecordPropsDefinition<Record<string, any>> | undefined'.       Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. ```

Comment: Hmmm... I've never passed props to a component constructor, I'll update.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to just do the default value though

Comment: Yeah, your answer is on good track, I will update my question a little bit so it is more specific to the core of the problem.

Comment: I could definetly set a default value and then set the name. However, I still believe it could be done in one step. What do you think?

Comment: Something to remember is that props are read-only, so you won't be able to overwrite it once set.

Comment: Btw I would get rid of the `required` section in your answer for default value. Because that still requires to pass a prop in the component constructor.

Comment: Interesting... I've not had the same issue when not invoking the constructor directly.

Comment: Any progress made?